# Laravel Source Encrypt

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-5, source-code-protection

Is there any ways available to encrypt the source code of Laravel? I do not want my client to see my source code. I want to encrypt all my PHP files and codes. Any idea?

FYI: laravel 5.2

Comment: If the code must be be executed on the same machine as the decryption key must reside, you cannot get encryption with actual confidentiality. You can only achieve obfuscation at best.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it using third party services like,

- [Zend Guard](http://www.zend.com/en/products/zend-guard)
- [IonCub](http://www.ioncube.com/php_encoder.php)
- [SourceGuardian](https://www.sourceguardian.com/protect_php_features.html)
- [phpSHIELD](http://www.phpshield.com/)

Comment: Hi @Hiren Makwana, Can the project be run on Apache after encoded?

Comment: May try this: https://github.com/SiavashBamshadnia/Laravel-Source-Encrypter (Laravel 5.5+)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. There are tools like ZendGuard and few others which can help to gaurd your source code.

However, ethically, it is not recommended. If your client is paying for the code, ideally, he owns the code. Just my personal view.

Comment: Client not pay for the code,just pay for licence.I have been tried zend guard but there was an error.

Comment: I purchased the ionCube Encoder. Is this application mine anymore? Why can't I access the source code? If I'm paying for the code, won't I be the owner?

Comment: @MertA. It depends on context when we purchase a license, we can't have code as we are not paying for complete development. However, if a client asks for custom development from scratch, and paying 100%+ development cost, he should not be locked to one developer, that's my view obviously and I follow that. Question mention laravel 5.2 so I believe its the latter case.

In the end, it depends on the developer, client and the contract between them.